# Android Resource Compilation Failed Error When I add an Image to drawable Folder

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I'm new to Android. I have made a simple app. When I try to generate signed bundle, I'm getting the following error.

[Error Message Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoZuk.png)

**Code:**

**build.gradle (project)**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (module)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cricketchirps"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

**gradle.properties**

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app"s APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="226dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/thermameter_pic"
        android:src="@drawable/temp1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDoKnow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_bold"
        android:text="@string/do_you_know"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp"
        android:text="@string/you_can_determin"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputNumber"
        android:layout_width="217dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/enter_numb_chirps"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTemp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/button_color"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/button_color"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="@string/get_temp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_bold"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/textview"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, Invalidate caches/restart. But I'm still getting the error.

I deleted the temp1.png from drawable folder and removed the ImageView completely. It worked fine. There was no error.

Can anyone please tell me why I'm getting this error and how to solve it?

Android Studio: 4.1

Build Tools: 30.0.2

Gradle Version: 6.5

Android Gradle Plugin Version: 4.1.0

**Update:**

I just converted the image from png to webp format. And it fixed my problem.
To convert image from png to webp in Android Studio, open the image > Right click > Convert to webp...

Answer (score 0):

Try to set image resource dynamically (i.e, within .java or .kt file)

JAVA -

```
ImageView img = findViewById("R.id.imageView2");
img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.temp1));
```

KOTLIN -

```
imageView2.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.temp1))
```

Comment: I converted the image to webp format. Now everything is working fine.